# Understanding the use of the % in Python string formatting

Tags: python

I have the following statement in python:

name = "SomeString"

```
 return ''.join(["%x" % sum([ord(c) for c in name])] + ["%x" % ord(c) for c in "%smscstr!" % name])[:14]
```

I struggling with the % in this case as I'm not that familiar with python.

I know what the %x is but not the next % before 'sum' and before 'name'. From what I've read it's to do with formatting so 'I think' I get the first one but not the one before 'name'.

Comment: If you are familiar with C it is similar to `printf()`, format string before the %, values after it.

Comment: @Michael Butscher I'm not too familiar with C. But % name... Does that use th "%x" format at the beginning and then append the two together? (ord(c)... and name. I'm confused.